# export stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, export, firebird

I am looking to create a procedure that returns another stored procedure `DLL` by its name but do not know how to do it exactly. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
example output

    SET TERM ^ ;

     CREATE or ALTER PROCEDURE MY_REPORTS (
       objid my_id)
     returns (
       docdate my_datetime)
as

begin

  some body

end^

    SET TERM ; ^
```

Your advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me... are you looking for a way to create SP which returns source code (DDL script) of another SP? What has it to do with DLL?

Answer (score 2):

You need access to "System Tables" like RDB$PROCEDURES and RDB$PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS.

`select p.RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME, p.RDB$PROCEDURE_SOURCE, pr.RDB$PARAMETER_NAME, 
        pr.RDB$PARAMETER_TYPE, iif(pr.RDB$PARAMETER_TYPE=0,'INPUT','OUTPUT') PARAM_TYPE
from RDB$PROCEDURES p
  left join RDB$PROCEDURE_PARAMETERS pr on p.RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME=pr.RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME
where p.RDB$PROCEDURE_NAME='CALCULAVTO'
order by pr.RDB$PARAMETER_TYPE, pr.RDB$PARAMETER_NUMBER`